# Automatically go to next line in vim

Tags: vim

One frustrating behavior in vim is that when i move my cursor right or left (respectively "l" or "h)" and i am at the end or the beginning of the line, my cursor doesn't move to first column of next line or last column of previous line.

Is there a way to change this behavior ?

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question but...

Comment: ...but it is a question regarding "software tools commonly used by programmers". :) (admittedly it's not a "problem that is unique to software development").

Comment: `set nocompatible` had disabled that feature in my `vim` configuration

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `whichwrap` setting to make `h` and `l` wrap around the start and end of individual lines:

```
set whichwrap+=h,l
```

However, Vim's documentation recommends against this, probably because it could have unexpected side effects (like breaking plugins, or changing how common key mappings work).

As an alternative, you can do what what Matti Virkkunen recommended:

```
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
```

This leaves `h` and `l` with their default behavior, but allows the left and right arrow keys to wrap around lines. (This is what I do, and it works well.)

You might also want to take a look at the `backspace` setting, to control how Backspace, Delete, Control+W, and Control+U work in Insert mode. I set mine like this:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

That allows me to backspace over pretty much everything.

For more info, see these topics in the Vim help:

```
:help 'whichwrap
:help 'backspace
```

Comment: Can you explain what these do? (specifically, what do `<`, `>`, `[`, and `]` mean?)

Comment: Here is a browser-friendly version of `:help 'whichwrap`: https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27whichwrap%27

Comment: @Nic `<` and `>` mean the left/right keys in normal and visual mode. `[` and `]` mean the left/right arrows in insert and replace mode. These options are explained in vim's documentation. Type `:help 'whichwrap'` for more info.

Answer (score 11):

Put the following into your .vimrc:

```
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
```

Comment: Can you explain what this does?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: The whichwrap setting specifies which keys will wrap to the next/previous line when pressed, and the character afterwards refer to the cursor keys in normal mode and insert mode respectively. You can add e.g. `h,l` to also have the vim movement keys wrap, if you wish.