# Vim - Trying to go to next line with right arrow key

Tags: vim, text, command-line, editor, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically go to next line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574027/automatically-go-to-next-line-in-vim)

Does anybody know why Vim does not allow to go to the next line using the right arrow key but only using up/down?

Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Zorgatone.

Comment: The short answer is `set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem by putting this in your vimrc file:

```
set whichwrap+=<,>,h,l,[,]
```

You can remove h and l if you don't want them to go to the next line.