# how to make vim go to next line when at last character and press right arrow key

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Automatically go to next line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574027/automatically-go-to-next-line-in-vim)

Here is my current [.vimrc configuration file](https://github.com/sntshkmr60/vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc).

Suppose I am on line `10` of any file, and at the last character too. Now here if the **Vim** were **gedit** (or I think any GUI editor) then pressing right arrow key would make me to line `11`. And same when I am on the first character of line `11`, then pressing left arrow key should make me go to last character of line `10`.

#### My Question:

Can I configure Vim to behave like other GUI editor and make me reach line `11` when I press right arrow key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add '<' and '>' to `whichwrap`:

```
set whichwrap+=<,>,[,]
```

See `help 'whichwrap'`.