# How to make cursor go to the next line when reaching the end of line in vim?

Tags: vim

When I am holding the "l" key in vim in command mode, the cursor goes to right. However, when it reaches the end of the line, it stops. I want it to behave differently, i.e. I want it to go to the next line when it goes right and reaches the end of line. How can I do so? Is there some configuration code that I can add to .vimrc file that changes the default behaviour of the cursor?

Comment: See `:help 'whichwrap'`.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer on net after learning the keyword 'whichwrap' in the comments.
After I searched the keyword, I come across the following link which has the answer:
[Automatically go to next line in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574027/automatically-go-to-next-line-in-vim)